# relation between diameter and central vertices

Tags: graph-theory

If the graph is a tree and the center of a graph is a vertex i.e only one cenral vertex then can we say that the diameter of the graph will be an even number?

Comment: What is your definition of a central vertex?  The center of a graph?  If a central vertex has two maximal paths leaving it that have the same length....

Comment: Central vertices are those vertices whose eccentricities are minimum in the graph.centre of a graph is the subgraph generated using only centre vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of central vertex $c$ is a vertex that minimizes the maximum distance to other vertices, and that minimum is called the radius $r$. Diameter is just the biggest distance between to vertices $v, w$.
The obvious relation is, from triangle inequality, that:

$$d = d(v, w) \leq d(v, c) + d(c, w) \leq 2 r$$

i.e. that the diameter is at most twice the radius.